# How to echo output as it is generated

Tags: php

How do I echo something for every iteration of the following loop:

```
<?
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
          // some (slow) logic
          echo $i;
    } 
?>
```

I would like to see the value of `$i` output as it runs, however this outputs nothing and then `0 1 2 3 4` after the script is executed.

Comment: Are you viewing output on the console or in a web browser?

Comment: Didn't you just give your own answer in your own question?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php comment #3

Comment: You're using a server-side technology (PHP). You need to use a client-side technology, like JavaScript to achieve this. See this link for an explanation between the two: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: PHP sends data to the browser after the script execution completes. You can use output buffering and the `flush()` function to override the default behavior.

Comment: +1, question is usefull

Comment: +1, the question should be reopened as it covers behavior in `PHP` that may not be readily apparent to a beginner.

Comment: `// some (slow) logic` edition is perhaps the more logical thing expected here, but is this a valid edition of this post?? @AD7six

Comment: Yes it exactly means what i want..sorry for not explaining it properly.

The loop was just for example...What i am trying to do doesn't run instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.  The key here is knowing what output_buffering value(default=4096) was set for your server.

```
ob_start();
$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096)."\r\n<span></span>\r\n";

for ($i=0; $i<25; $i++) {
      echo $buffer.$i;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
          sleep(1);
}       

ob_end_flush();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Comment: Tried this but it still executes the whole script and then displays the data.

Comment: what's the value of output_buffering in your server?  Some servers won't flush the ouput until the buffer size is met

Comment: Its at 4096..Should i change it ?

Comment: is output buffering on? I just tried this both in the command line and in the browser via apache and it's working

Comment: Yes on php.ini it is set to output_buffering = On. Doesnt work still

Answer (score -2):

So build a string, then echo the string:

```
$str = '';
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
   $str .= $i;
}
echo $str;
```

Note that this, in practice, changes nothing. Such a tiny loop will execute almost instantly and display almost instantly. If you're doing this in a browser context, you'll likely get all the digits coming across in a single network packet and the browser rendering/displaying them at once as well.

Comment: The OP wants send output after every loop, not once at the end. "_How do i echo a string every time the function completes a loop_"

Comment: While this doesn't answer the OP's question, you do have a good point: ***"If you're doing this in a browser context, you'll likely get all the digits coming across in a single network packet and the browser rendering/displaying them at once as well."***

Comment: "after the function completes a loop", which is exactly what my snippet does. after the loop completes, it echoes the string. Tell me how my code is wrong?

Comment: The OP appears to have misused the word 'function'. As I read the question, he wants to send output to the browser at the end of each iteration of the loop. Your version sends all of the output at once after the entire loop has finished executing, which is exactly the behavior the OP currently observes.

Comment: perhaps the OP means after every iteration... which is exactly what the OP's code is doing to begin with.

Comment: True, if viewed on a console. However, the OP is viewing output in a web browser, so it _appears_ as though all of the output is generated at once. Output buffering/flusing is the way to produce the effect the OP desires.

Comment: only if the browser cooperates too. just because the server is flushing output doesn't mean the browser is going to follow along in lockstep.